# How to filter out a javascript hash map by only including values of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, hashmap

So the problem I am facing is something like this. Let's say I have the following:

```
let surfaces: Map<any, any> = new Map([{"83.1" => Object}, {"84.1" => Object}])
let arr1 = ["83.1"]
```

So, the results I want is something like this.

```
let surfaces: Map<any, any> = [{"83.1" => Object}]
```

However, whenever I try iterating through it ends up deleting all the keys present in the map. This is what I did:

```
for (let [key, value] of surfaces.entries()) {
            for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
                if (arr1[i] != key) {
                    surfaces.delete(key);
                }
            }
        }
```

I also tried it the other way round such as this one:

```
for (let k of surfaces.keys()) {
            for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
                if (k === arr1[i]) {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    surfaces.delete(k);
                }
            }
        }
```

But it always ends up deleting all the keys. I was wondering what the right way might be to go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Right now your first two lines of code are invalid/pseudocode, so anyone who wants to work on this would need to first fix that instead of getting started immediately.  If you make it easier for others to engage with the issue, you increase the chance of getting a good answer.  (If you do decide to [edit] to do this and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me.)  Good luck!

Comment: Your first attempt should work when you change the condition to `===` instead of `!==`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let surfaces = [{"83.1": {}}, {"84.1" :{}}]
let arr1 = ["83.1"]

surfaces = surfaces.filter(s => {
  let key = Object.keys(s)
  if(arr1.includes(key[0])){
    return s;
  }
})

console.log(surfaces)
```